# Rename variable scope of saved model in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible to rename the variable scope of a given model in tensorflow?

For instance, I created a logistic regression model for MNIST digits, based on the tutorial:

```
with tf.variable_scope('my-first-scope'):
    NUM_IMAGE_PIXELS = 784
    NUM_CLASS_BINS = 10
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, NUM_IMAGE_PIXELS])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, NUM_CLASS_BINS])

    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NUM_IMAGE_PIXELS,NUM_CLASS_BINS]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NUM_CLASS_BINS]))

    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
    saver = tf.train.Saver([W, b])

... # some training happens

saver.save(sess, 'my-model')
```

Now I want to reload the saved model in the `'my-first-scope'` variable scope and then save everything again to a new file and under a new variable scope of `'my-second-scope'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`tf.contrib.framework.list_variables`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/contrib.framework/checkpoint_utilities#list_variables) and [`tf.contrib.framework.load_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/contrib.framework/checkpoint_utilities#load_variable) as follows to achieve your goal :

```
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session().as_default() as sess:
  with tf.variable_scope('my-first-scope'):
    NUM_IMAGE_PIXELS = 784
    NUM_CLASS_BINS = 10
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, NUM_IMAGE_PIXELS])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, NUM_CLASS_BINS])

    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NUM_IMAGE_PIXELS,NUM_CLASS_BINS]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NUM_CLASS_BINS]))

    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
    saver = tf.train.Saver([W, b])
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  saver.save(sess, 'my-model')

vars = tf.contrib.framework.list_variables('.')
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session().as_default() as sess:

  new_vars = []
  for name, shape in vars:
    v = tf.contrib.framework.load_variable('.', name)
    new_vars.append(tf.Variable(v, name=name.replace('my-first-scope', 'my-second-scope')))

  saver = tf.train.Saver(new_vars)
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  saver.save(sess, 'my-new-model')
```

Comment: This requires that you have constructed the graph and everything using the previous scope name, since to restore the checkpoint you need to have defined the graph.
If you just have the checkpoint file, can you replace a scope name within it ?

Answer (score 28):

Based on keveman's answer, I created a python script, which you can execute to rename the variables of any TensorFlow checkpoint:

https://gist.github.com/batzner/7c24802dd9c5e15870b4b56e22135c96

You can replace substrings in the variable names and add a prefix to all names. Call the script with

```
python tensorflow_rename_variables.py --checkpoint_dir=path/to/dir
```

with the optional arguments

```
--replace_from=substr --replace_to=substr --add_prefix=abc --dry_run
```

Here is the script's core function:

```
def rename(checkpoint_dir, replace_from, replace_to, add_prefix, dry_run=False):
    checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        for var_name, _ in tf.contrib.framework.list_variables(checkpoint_dir):
            # Load the variable
            var = tf.contrib.framework.load_variable(checkpoint_dir, var_name)

            # Set the new name
            new_name = var_name
            if None not in [replace_from, replace_to]:
                new_name = new_name.replace(replace_from, replace_to)
            if add_prefix:
                new_name = add_prefix + new_name

            if dry_run:
                print('%s would be renamed to %s.' % (var_name, new_name))
            else:
                print('Renaming %s to %s.' % (var_name, new_name))
                # Rename the variable
                var = tf.Variable(var, name=new_name)

        if not dry_run:
            # Save the variables
            saver = tf.train.Saver()
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            saver.save(sess, checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path)
```

Example:

```
python tensorflow_rename_variables.py --checkpoint_dir=path/to/dir --replace_from=scope1 --replace_to=scope1/model --add_prefix=abc/
```

will rename the variable `scope1/Variable1` to `abc/scope1/model/Variable1`.

Comment: I am getting this error with the script: ValueError: Couldn't find 'checkpoint' file or checkpoints in given directory ./fi

Comment: @ryuzakinho, you need to specify a directory that contains a `checkpoint` file. See https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#checkpoint_files for more info.

Comment: Actually, I had write_state=False for some reason. Hence, it was not creating a checkpoint file.

Comment: I encounted an error when the graph is too large.  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5884 . `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot serialize protocol buffer of type tensorflow.GraphDef as the serialized size (3363746871bytes) would be larger than the limit (2147483647 bytes)`

Comment: Indeed this approach seems to cause the .meta file size to blow up.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple script to rename variables and in this way to change their scope name:

```
import tensorflow as tf

OLD_CHECKPOINT_FILE = "model.ckpt"
NEW_CHECKPOINT_FILE = "model_renamed.ckpt"

vars_to_rename = {
    "scope_1/var1": "scope_2/var1",
    "scope_1/var2": "scope_2/var2",
}
new_checkpoint_vars = {}
reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(OLD_CHECKPOINT_FILE)

for old_name in reader.get_variable_to_shape_map():
    if old_name in vars_to_rename:
        new_name = vars_to_rename[old_name]
    else:
        new_name = old_name
    new_checkpoint_vars[new_name] = tf.Variable(reader.get_tensor(old_name))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver(new_checkpoint_vars)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    saver.save(sess, NEW_CHECKPOINT_FILE)
```